# Saturation function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, discontinuity

In Simulink, there is a function called [Saturation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/saturation.html):

[image: Saturation]

Is there function like that in *Mathematica*? If yes, what is it called?

Comment: Look up `Clip[]`.

Comment: @J.M. exactly what I was looking for! :) but why this name? I was not able to find it no matter how much I searched.

Comment: It's called `Clip` because it clips. Like `Rescale` because it rescales; like `Sort` because it sorts; like...

Comment: For me, a "saturation function" should look more like the logistic function (`LogisticSigmoid`)...

Comment: Honestly, I hate the Simulink function name, but I guess that's the preferred term of art in that system. `Clip[]`, as Henrik notes, does [exactly what it says on the tin](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin).

Comment: @Henrik, for that application, I'd combine `Rescale[]` and `LogisticSigmoid[]`. ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I guess that I was biased towards that naming because of undergrade MATLAB requirements....

Comment: My question has been answered but the duplicate flag is wrong. My question is not the same as [the one mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10484/how-to-change-specific-values-in-a-list) though the answer is the same.